# How to handle two functions together in KeyEventArgs...VC++2010?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

The following will describe in details

I have a class

```
//MyDataHeaders.h
public ref class MyGlobalData {
//blah...blah...blah...
public: static System::Void Pty_NameCell( System::Object^ Sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^ e) {
//blah..blah...
}
};
```

And in Form2 I have a Sub...like the following..

```
//Form2.h
public: static System::Void MySupplier_LstVew() {
//blah..blah..
}
Form2_load() {
textBox2->KeyDown += gcnew KeyEventHandler(MyGlobalData::Pty_NameCell); //OK
};
```

But Here I want to use

```
textBox2->KeyDown +=delegate { gcnew KeyEventHandler(MyGlobalData::Pty_NameCell); MySupplier_LstVew(); };
```

How to declare the `textBox2-> Keydwon` event with `(MyGlobalData::Pty_NameCell),MySupplier_LstVew()` together?
Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can do

```
textBox2->KeyDown += gcnew KeyEventHandler(MyGlobalData::Pty_NameCell);
textBox2->KeyDown += gcnew KeyEventHandler(MySupplier_LstVew);
```